Shell Scriptでホームディレクトリの中にディレクトリを自動で作成して入りたいです。
実行環境
ChromeOSのcrostini上のDebian
やりたいこと・目的
Shell Scriptでホームディレクトリの中にstudyJSディレクトリを自動で作成して入りたいです。
なお、ホームディレクトリの中に既にstudyJSが存在している場合は、新しくディレクトリを作成せずに次の処理に進めるような機能を実装したいです。
現状だとどのような問題があるか
studyJSディレクトリが存在した場合に、mkdir: cannot create directory ‘studyJS’: File existsというエラーが出現します。
再現手順

ホームディレクトリに「studyJS」というディレクトリを作成します。
ホームディレクトリで下のShell Scriptを実行します。

#!/bin/sh -eu

# JavaScriptの学習用ディレクトリを作成し、その中に入る
if ! -d "$HOME/studyJS/"; then
    echo "JavaScriptの学習用ディレクトリstudyJSが存在しないので作成します"
    mkdir "$HOME/studyJS/"
    echo "studyJSディレクトリを作成しました"
fi

cd studyJS || { echo "studyJSディレクトリに移動できませんでした"; exit 1; }
echo "studyJSの中に入りました"


if ! -d "$HOME/studyJS/"; then は if [ ! -d "$HOME/studyJS/" ]; then でしょう。([ ] が抜けています) それから、シェルスクリプト内でディレクトリを移動しても実行元のプロセスには反映されません。(実行後もカレントディレクトリはホームディレクトリのままです)

示されたコードにはいくつか問題がありそうです

$HOME/studyJS で統一できていない
if 文の行に間違いがある

ホームディレクトリで作業を行うのが前提だとしても, 他の位置で誤動作するかもしれないのはあまり良くないでしょう。変数に入れておくとよいかも
OUTDIR=$HOME/studyJS
mkdir $OUTDIR
cd $OUTDIR

if文は, bashが利用できるなら help if で内容を確認できます
(bashは sh / dash の拡張版なので, ある程度は同じ)
参考: bash(1)    GNU Bourne-Again SHell
たとえば以下のように (終了ステータスにより条件分岐)
if mkdir tmpdir; then echo "作成できた"; fi

当該行では if ! -d "$HOME/studyJS/"; then 〜

-d というコマンドを実行し, 終了ステータスが 0 でなければ then以降を実行, の意味
-d コマンドがあればよいが, 無ければ「見つからない」的なメッセージが出ていたはず
shebang のエラー停止の指定でも, 終了ステータス返す以前に, 実行さえできないので停止しない

ディレクトリーが存在するかどうか調べるには testコマンドを用います
help test で確認可能 (bashの場合, test はシェル組み込み関数として存在する)
test(1)    ファイル種別の確認や値の比較を行う
test コマンドと終了ステータスの確認
test -d "path/to/dir"; echo $?

また, test コマンドは 1文字のコマンド [ として利用することも多く, 後者をよく見かけるかもしれません
コマンド(あるいは組み込み関数)なので, コマンド名のあとに少なくとも 1つ以上のスペースなど区切りが必要なので注意。[ を使うなら, 引数の最後に ] が必要になりその際も区切りに注意したほうがよいでしょう
if文の行に [, ] を指定した例
if [ ! -d "$HOME/studyJS/" ]
  then
    echo "作成します"

(略)


また, コメントにあるように
cd を行い, 続けて何か処理を行うならよいが
単に終了するだけなら, プロセス終了と共にそのプロセスが持つカレントディレクトリ情報も意味を持たなくなるので注意

./hoge.sh だと新しいシェルを起動するので cd 結果は失われますが source ./hoge.sh だと現 shell 上で実行するので cd 結果は失われないですよね。この辺新しいスクリプトを書くのでなくて ~/.bash_profile あたりに書くとそれなりに効きますよ。その是非は置いといて。

alias を定義するとよいでしょう。alias studyJS='{ test -d "$HOME/studyJS/" || mkdir "$HOME/studyJS/"; } && cd "$HOME/studyJS/"'

色々な努力を台無しにしてしまいますが、mkdirには-pオプションが存在します。

-p, --parents
ディレクトリが存在していてもエラーを返さない。必要に応じて親ディレクトリを作成する

なので、何も考えずにとにかく作らせる手もあります。
mkdir -p "$HOME/studyJS/"

